# swift subviews not updating after unwind segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am writing a basic iOS calendar app using swift. Currently, my main view contains one subview -- "month view" -- which contains five "week views" each of which contain 7 "day views." The main view controller is set as the delegate for each day subview, each of which can be touched to trigger a segue to a new "day view controller" which loads in all the info for the selected day. The day view controller also has one button "done" button on the top nav bar which triggers an unwind segue back to the main view controller.

The problem is: after the unwind segue, the data from the "day" in the day view controller is passed successfully back to the main view controller (I know this from debugging my data model), but the view of the main view controller will not update to properly display the info from the updated day.

I have tried calling "setNeedsDisplay" and "setNeedsLayout" from the segue and from "viewWillAppear" and "viewDidAppear" on my main "month view" as well as on each individual "day view" but nothing updates. I have also tried removing and adding each individual day subview (just to get something to happen) but this causes the new day with the correct info to be superimposed over the old day. I have searched all over for the solution to this. I believe I may just be missing a certain swift design principle. Thank you very much in advance!

Here is the code for the segue:

```
    @IBAction func unwindToCalendar(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? dayUIViewController {
        var tag = sourceViewController.tag
        let dayOfWeek = tag%10
        tag=tag/10
        let weekOfMonth = tag%10

        monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek] = sourceViewController.day
        //monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek].updateLabel()
        monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek].setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Updating the relevant property of the day subview gives me the desired effect (i.e. when I transition back to the calendar view, the selected day reflects the changes I made from the day view controller).

So replacing this:

```
monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek] = sourceViewController.day
```

with this:

```
monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek].dayOfMonth = sourceViewController.day.dayOfMonth
monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek].updateLabel()
```

Gives the desired "visual" result. But why would replacing the entire day view with a new day view not achieve this result as well?

Comment: What _is_ `monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth].dayList[dayOfWeek)`? It looks like some sort of _data_, not a _view_.

Comment: the month view has a property containing an array of week subviews and the week subviews have a similar property of day subviews (all of which are added to their parent views as subviews before being added to this array). I set it up this way so I could more easily access the day views via array indexes.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Have you looked to see whether, by any wild chance, this is all happening on a background thread? Any time there is some unaccountable delay in updating the interface, I find it is very often caused by accidentally trying to update the interface off the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the fact that the "day data" and the view itself live in two different places, which I was overlooking. In my original code, I was replacing the relevant array entry with a new "day view", but the relevant subview in the calendar view was still the old "day view". I need to replace the day subview in the calendar with the new "day view" from the segue:

```
//make life easier with a variable
let thisWeek = monthView.weekList[weekOfMonth]

//remove the old subview from the calendar
thisWeek.dayList[dayOfWeek].removeFromSuperview()

//replace the old day with the new day in the data
thisWeek.dayList[dayOfWeek] = sourceViewController.day

//add the new day as a subview to its "week parent view"
thisWeek.addSubview(thisWeek.dayList[dayOfWeek])

//nicely layout the new day subviews
thisWeek.layoutSubviews()
```

Although I've solved this particular problem, I still welcome comments on design principles as I am fairly new to swift and MVC design. Thank you!